# Taking the first data of the results in voice recognition

Tags: android, voice-recognition

In my project i will use voice recognition. In the codes of voice recognition, an arraylist returns on activity result. But i just want to take the first data in the list. i mean in the project users will use speak button, speak and then see the results. And then there will be continue button that shows the first data of the results. How can i pass the result parameter to another activity class. But not as the originally list, just a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this code

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            ArrayList<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
            matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);


            if(matches.lenght()>0)  {
                 result = matches.get(0)

                 //Time to create the new intent to the other activity  
                 Intent i  = new Intent (Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
                 i.putExtra("RESULT", result); //RESULT is the key 
                 startActivityForResult(i,ID); // or startActivity(i)
            }
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Then in the other activity you must to uget the bundle and extrat the string

```
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if( (bundle!=null) && (bundle.contains("RESULT"){
        String text = bundle.getString("RESULT");

    }
    else{
        //other things
        return;
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much. It gives error(The method lenght() is undefined for the type ArrayList<String>). And What did you define the result?

Comment: Sorry ece, i write the code quick, i supose you understand the code.

matches.size() to check the lenght/size of the array.

String result